# Error in Android studio New Application

Tags: android

Whenever i start new application in android studio this error pop ups

what should i do[image]

Comment: can you please add the build.gradle file to the question

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is because your Compile SDK version is below 23.

Make  `compileSdkVersion 23` in your buiild.gradle file and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

You should use  **`compileSdkVersion 23 in your build.gradle`**.

First make sure that you set

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Gradle** .

Try this way .I hope it works .